# Javascript calender skipping dates

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

This all appears to be functioning correctly in all other browsers apart from IE10, when selecting a month/year it will randomly skip a month.

An error is thrown every time the date is changed, however it appears that this error doesn't always cause an issue

`Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference`

Snippet of code being used:

```
var vals;

if (typeof(targetedControl.Validators) != "undefined") {
    vals = targetedControl.Validators;
}
else {
    if (targetedControl.tagName.toLowerCase() == "label") {
        targetedControl = document.getElementById(targetedControl.htmlFor);
        vals = targetedControl.Validators;
    }
}

var i;

for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    ValidatorValidate(vals[i], null, event);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems vals is null/probably the targetedControl cannot be found... this should let you know:

```
if(!targetedControl || !vals)
{
    alert('Control Not Found!');
}
else
{
    for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        ValidatorValidate(vals[i], null, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer, more an idea on how to find it :P You should of posted as a comment. Thank you though

Comment: wait so you downvoted me, because i helped you find your problem and resolve it? wow! Thank YOU though! and by the way, the solution i gave you, if you remove the alert, actually solves your problem and the error won't come up anymore. You're welcome though!